# Раздельное и слитное написание НЕ

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Почему нужно писать: "недействующая организация, неотчитывающаяся организация" (НЕ слитно), но, например, "Организация, не отчитывающаяся по состоянию на..."  - пишется раздельно с частицей НЕ

Comment: Спасибо всем большое за участие. Я тоже 
нашла у Ушаковой правила написания причастий. Ура! Как хорошо, что есть у кого спросить, а главное - получить подсказочку. Ура.

Answer (score 1):

Частица НЕ с полными причастиями пишется раздельно, если есть зависимые от причастия слова: "Организация, не отчитывающаяся по состоянию на..." (вообще-то не мешало бы больше контекста давать в вопросе!). Если же зависимых слов нет, НЕ пишется с причастием слитно: "недействующая организация", "неотчитывающаяся организация". Более подробно о других случаях правописания НЕ с причастиями можно почитать, например, у Розенталя (http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/20.htm, §70.Правописание не с причастиями).

Answer (score 0):

Школьное правило 6 класса гласит: НЕ с причастиями (употребляющимися без НЕ) пишется раздельно, если образовано от глаг. сов. вида; имеет приставку (кроме НЕ); имеет -ова-/-ева; имеет зависимые слова. Похоже, здесь есть зависимые слова: "по состоянию на..." Значит, НЕ пишется раздельно.  Конечно, я перепутала правило!:)

Comment: Инна, Вы не перепутали правило о написании Н/HH с правилом о слитном написании причастий???